Synchronize double-buffering entirely at compile time, akin to thread::scope?
In double buffering, the main thread mutates buffer A at the same time as a background thread mutates buffer B, then when each thread is done A moves to the background and B the foreground. (In my case the "background thread" is really the GPU but I don't think that's important here.)
For just one buffer this can be done easily with scoped threads. You can lend the buffer to the other thread, do some work in parallel, and then access it when the scope is over. But this doesn't work with two buffers, because after you start the background work for A, you want to wait for the background work for B, not A. The scopes have to overlap, not like a stack, but like roof tiles, with each one beginning before the previous one ends (if the analogy makes sense).
Intuitively this should be possible by passing two closures, one that does the foreground work for A and then kicks off the background work, and a similar one for B, and then call them in a loop. But this doesn't work:
use core::marker::PhantomData;
struct Scope<'scope, 'env: 'scope> {
    // Both lifetimes are invariant
    scope: PhantomData<&'scope mut &'scope ()>,
    env: PhantomData<&'env mut &'env ()>,
}

impl<'scope> Scope<'scope, '_> {
    fn do_it(&'scope self, _: &'scope mut i32) {}
}

fn double_buffer<'env, F1, F2>(_: F1, _: F2)
    where F1: for<'s1> FnMut(&'s1 Scope<'s1, 'env>),
          F2: for<'s2> FnMut(&'s2 Scope<'s2, 'env>)
{/* ... */}

fn main() {
    let (mut a, mut b) = (0, 0);
    
    double_buffer(|s| {
        a = 0;  // Main thread
        s.do_it(&mut a); // Background thread
        // a can't be accessed here.
    }, |s| {
        b = 0;
        s.do_it(&mut b);
    });
}

The compiler complains that the captured variable escapes the FnMut, and sure enough changing them to FnOnce compiles. I even tried rewriting it using async:
use core::future::Future;
fn double_buffer_async<'env, F1, U1, F2, U2>(_: F1, _: F2)
    where F1: FnMut() -> U1,
          F2: FnMut() -> U2,
          U1: Future<Output=()> + 'env,
          U2: Future<Output=()> + 'env
{/* ... */}

async fn do_it(_: &mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let (mut a, mut b) = (0, 0);
    
    double_buffer_async(|| async {
        a = 0;
        do_it(&mut a).await;
        a = 0;
    }, || async {
        b = 0;
        do_it(&mut b).await;
        b = 0;
    })
}

But this doesn't work for exactly the same reason. Is this pattern even expressible in the type system? Or am I missing something?

How do you know when it's safe to swap the buffers?

Why don't you just pass a single closure that takes an exclusive reference as a parameter, and provide references to the two buffers?

Example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc03344b5cbd6e8a129ee05b1d1f43de (Note the futures need to be boxed currently since there isn't another way to specify that the returned future captures the lifetime of the argument.) If you actually do need two different functions, you can do that as well.

Do you need async, or you only tried to circumvent the problem using it?

I don't quite understand the do_it function. Why don't you just swap the buffers, then wait for both foreground and background, and then swap again? Why does the buffer have to be actively handed from the foreground to the background thread?

@ChayimFriedman do_it would store a value in s similar to a JoinHandle that double_buffer can wait for. @cdhowie Good idea. @Finomnis That's a great point, thanks!

It turns out I was missing something, which is that thread::scope can do this already:
use std::thread::scope;

fn main() {
    let (mut a, mut b) = (0, 0);
    loop {
        scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                a = 1;
            });
            b = 0;
        });
        scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                b = 1;
            });
            a = 0;
        });
    }
}


Note that spawning a thread is quite expensive operation. It is better to use a threadpool.
